90s horror movie with a girl in a room full of water
It might be a Dario Argento movie, for some reason I thought it was, however I could be wrong.
The scene shows a young girl, between 16 and 21, sitting in a room with stark white walls and white floor.  In the floor is a hatch, also painted white, like the kind you would find on a ship. It's round with the metal device that you turn to open the hatch. She opens the hatch and peers in.  It is a room full of water and there are tables floating around with fancy table clothes like a fancy dinner was set-up for a party of some kind.  There are dead bodies floating around too. It looks like a fancy dinner was held and the room was flooded killing everyone there.  While she is looking her bracelet falls off her arm and she goes in to get it.
That is all I remember. I intended to look it up at the time, however, when I got to looking to see what the movie was there was no listing I could find for it.  Please let me know if anyone saw this movie and the title please.  I would like to see it.  I don't know how old it is but I believe it was sometime before or during the 90's.

Sounds more or less like a scene from Dario Argento's Inferno from 1980.

Rose Elliot (Miracle), a poet living alone in New York City, finds an ancient book called The Three Mothers. It tells of three evil sisters who rule the world with sorrow, tears, and darkness. The book, written by an architect named Varelli, reveals that the three dwell inside separate homes that had been built for them by the architect in Rome, Freiburg, and New York. Rose suspects that she is living in one of the buildings and writes to her brother Mark (McCloskey) in Rome, urging him to visit her. Using clues provided in the book as a guide, Rose searches the cellar of her building and discovers a hole in the floor which leads to a water-filled ballroom. She accidentally drops her keys and enters the water to find them. After she reclaims the keys, a putrid corpse suddenly rises from the depths, frightening her.

You can see it here [Warning: A Bit Graphic]:




Movies tend to be graphic in general, hehe ;)
